# Showing no point in the rationals (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$) has a precompact neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm studying for a Topology exam and I'm reviewing my professor's notes. In the notes, he writes that no point $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ has a precompact neighborhood $U$ (where we define $A \subset\mathbb{R}$ to be precompact if $cl(A)$ is compact). This does not seem right to me. Let $U=(-1,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. This is a neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. And $cl(U) = [-1,1]$, which is compact. Am I missing something?

Comment: The closure of $(-1,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $[-1,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, which is not compact since, for example, the open cover by $U_n=\left([-1,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n})\cup(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{n},1]\right)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have a finite sub-cover.

Comment: Ah, I was being silly and computed the closure of $U$ incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: You computed the closure in $\mathbb{R}$, but from the conclusion and the 'as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$' it looks like they mean in the topological space $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology induced as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the closure **in $\Bbb Q$**, not in $\Bbb R$. And in the rationals the closure is $[-1,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ which is not compact, as there is a rational sequence in it (converging in $\Bbb R$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, say) that has no convergence subsequence (in $\Bbb Q$ nor in $[-1,1] \cap \Bbb Q$).